# how to configure squid to use ssh tunnel for external sites?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, squid

I have a setup where I have ubuntu as squid proxy server at my home. All computers and ipad at my home use that ubuntu as proxy server. Now I want squid to redirect all request to ec2 instance for browsing. For example if I am browsing site www.example.com from my home computer, it goes to squid proxy on the same network, now instead of directly serving pages from internet, I want squid proxy to make ssh tunnel to ec2 instance and get pages from www.example.com through ec2 instance. EC2 instance is ubuntu again.

I figured out how to configure suqid to cater to my home computers but not sure how should I setup squid to tunnel to ec2 to cater to internet rather than directly going internet. Any pointers here will be helpful.

Attached is the image of my home setup.

[home network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD2UI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify if you want to use your EC2 instance as an additional gateway, so for example something like this:

```
client -> somepage.domain1.com -> lan squid -> lan internet
client -> somepage.domain2.com -> lan squid -> ec2 -> internet
```

Is that what you mean?  If so, I'd first caution that you'll be charged for network traffic for anything leaving your EC2 instance - and that could get costly.

I think what you might be interested in is setting up a squid cache_peer.  Take a look at this document on the subject

https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheHierarchy